# Skipping records in subtable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write query, that is selecting few things from 2 tables. 
Unfortunately I stuck on following problem: in table

```
Person.BusinessEntityAdress
```

You store key to another table with people addresses, but some records got 2 or more keys, and my point is to select just one of those keys, and skip rest. 
I'm using AdventureWorks2012 Database. 
Here's a [link](http://www.sqldatadictionary.com/AdventureWorks2012/Person.BusinessEntityAddress.html), where you can read about this database. 
So far, this is my query:

```
SELECT 
    pp.FirstName AS CUS_FirstName,
    pp.FirstName + pp.LastName AS CUS_Name,
    pp.LastName AS CUS_LastName, 
    pa.AddressLine1 AS CUS_AddressLine1, 
    pa.AddressLine2 AS CUS_AddressLine2,
    pp.BusinessEntityID AS CUS_CleanOrgID, --ID klienta
    CUS_SRCOrgID = '0' --ID źródła danych
FROM Person.Person pp
LEFT JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress pb
ON pp.BusinessEntityID = pb.BusinessEntityID
LEFT JOIN Person.Address pa
    ON pb.AddressID=pa.AddressID
ORDER BY pp.BusinessEntityID;
```

Comment: What do you mean "skip those who got more than one"?  You only want records that have one address?

Comment: Do you mean to skip records that have a FK with two or more tables??!!!
That doesn't sound right!!

Comment: Sorry, I took it wrong. I mean to select just one table with address, don't need rest of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subselect to limit to new newest `BusinessEntityAddress` in case of more than one `BusinessEntityAddress` for one `Person` 
N.B. I imagine that `Id` is the PK on `BusinessEntityAddress`

```
SELECT 
  pp.FirstName AS CUS_FirstName,
  pp.FirstName + pp.LastName AS CUS_Name,
  pp.LastName AS CUS_LastName, 
  pa.AddressLine1 AS CUS_AddressLine1, 
  pa.AddressLine2 AS CUS_AddressLine2,
  pp.BusinessEntityID AS CUS_CleanOrgID, --ID klienta
  CUS_SRCOrgID = '0' --ID źródła danych
FROM Person.Person pp
 LEFT JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress pb
  ON pp.BusinessEntityID = pb.BusinessEntityID
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Person.BusinessEntityAddress pb2
                    WHERE pp.BusinessEntityID = pb2.BusinessEntityID
                      AND pb2.Id > pb.Id)
 LEFT JOIN Person.Address pa
  ON pb.AddressID=pa.AddressID
ORDER BY pp.BusinessEntityID;
```