# Delete doublon inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select only top 1 comp from budget in order to delete duplicate records

```
update r
   set Comp = t.Comp
from [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Vente]r with (NOLOCK) inner join
     [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Budget] t
     on t.[Code Site] = r.[Code Site] and
        t.[Code Rayon] = substring(r.[Code Structure],1,4) and
        t.[Date Time] = convert(date,r.[Date Time])
where r.[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000';
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Why do you want top 1 so you can duplicates? Not sure I follow that. And if you are trying to delete why are you using an update?

Comment: Update statement with NOLOCK, at least I wouldn't like to find out what could happen...

Comment: Just so you are aware. Using NOLOCK in an update like this can corrupt your indexes and the syntax has been deprecated since 2005. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3172/avoid-using-nolock-on-sql-server-update-and-delete-statements/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
with topComp as (
  select t.[Code Site], t.[Code Rayon], t.[Date Time], max(t.[Comp])
  from [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Budget] t
  group by t.[Code Site], t.[Code Rayon], t.[Date Time]
);

update r
   set Comp = t.Comp
from [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Vente]r with (NOLOCK) inner join
     topComp t
     on t.[Code Site] = r.[Code Site] and
        t.[Code Rayon] = substring(r.[Code Structure],1,4) and
        t.[Date Time] = convert(date,r.[Date Time])
where r.[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple matches to the `budget` table and you only want one.  If so, then use `cross apply` instead of `join`.  For instance, to get the most recent record:

```
update r
   set Comp = t.Comp
from [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Vente]r with (NOLOCK) cross apply
     (select top 1 t.*
      from [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Budget] t
      where t.[Code Site] = r.[Code Site] and
            t.[Code Rayon] = substring(r.[Code Structure],1,4) and
            t.[Date Time] = convert(date,r.[Date Time])
      order by t.[Date Time] desc
     ) t
where r.[Date Time] >= '2015-01-01 00:0:00.000';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the same method as in [Skipping records in subtable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33081404/1183297).
If there is no `Id` column, you can do the greater than on `[Date Time]`